# Order of links in Settings Charm

Tags: settings, winjs

Does anyone know how I can position a link inside the settings charm to always appear at the bottom?

Our UI team would like the "Sign out" link to always be position last, unfortunately the "Permissions" link, which is automatically added, shows below it, even though I use the append call on the applicationCommands object.

```
var signOutCommand = new Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsCommand(
    "sign-out",
    "Sign out",
    signOutHandler,
);
e.detail.e.request.applicationCommands.append(signOutCommand);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found anything explicitly stating so, but I don't think it's possible to get in below the Permissions link.